# Drawing ellipse that passes through specified coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw an ellipse that must pass through `(0, -1)`, `(0, 1)`, `(-1, 0)`, `(1, 0)`, `(1, -1)` and `(-1, 1)`. My MWE is below. I know that, I'm missing some math here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [help lines] (-2, -2) grid (2, 2);
\draw[rotate=45] (0, 0) ellipse (0.5cm and 1.5cm);

\filldraw[black] (0, 0) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (0, 1) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (1, 0) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (-1, 0) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (0, -1) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (1, -1) circle(1.5pt);
\filldraw[black] (-1, 1) circle(1.5pt);

\draw[<->] (-2.0, 0) -- (2.0, 0) node[right]{\footnotesize $X_{1}$};
\draw[<->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) node[above]{\footnotesize $X_{2}$};

\node[above right] at (0, 1)   {\tiny $\left(0, 1\right)$}; 
\node[above right] at (1, 0)   {\tiny $\left(1, 0\right)$}; 
\node[above left]   at (-1, 0)  {\tiny $\left(-1, 0\right)$}; 
\node[below right] at (0, -1)  {\tiny $\left(0, -1\right)$}; 
\node[below right] at (1, -1)  {\tiny $\left(1, -1\right)$}; 
\node[above left]   at (-1,  1)  {\tiny $\left(-1, 1\right)$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

The equation of the ellipse is $X_1^2 + X_1 X_2 + X_2^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Output

[image]

You can manually perform the computations as suggested by JoeDub. You can then change

```
\draw[rotate=45] (0, 0) ellipse (0.5cm and 1.5cm);
```

into

```
\draw[rotate=45] (0, 0) ellipse (0.82cm and 1.4cm);
```

### Code

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99714/drawing-ellipse-that-passes-through-specified-coordinates#99714
\documentclass[border=5,convert={density=150}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [help lines] (-2, -2) grid (2, 2);
\draw[rotate=45,color=blue,very thick] (0, 0) ellipse (0.82cm and 1.4cm);

\foreach \x/\y in {0/0, 0/1, 1/0, -1/0, 0/-1, 1/-1, -1/1}
\filldraw[black] (\x, \y) circle(1.5pt);

\draw[<->] (-2.0, 0) -- (2.0, 0) node[right]{\footnotesize $X_{1}$};
\draw[<->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) node[above]{\footnotesize $X_{2}$};

\foreach \x/\y/\direction in {0/1/above right, 1/0/above right, -1/0/above left, 0/-1/below left, 1/-1/below right, -1/1/above left}
\node [\direction] at (\x,\y) {\tiny $\left(\x, \y\right)$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also do this without rotation by specifying your major axis and minor axis (*first axis* and *second axis* in the manual) through the use of the `\pgfpathellipse` command. Here it is with your MWE.

```
\documentclass[border=5,convert={density=150}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [help lines] (-2, -2) grid (2, 2);
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpointxy{1}{-1}}{\pgfpointxy{0.58}{0.58}} % Create an ellipse with one end of major axis passing through (1,-1) and with one end of minor axis at (0.58,0.58)
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\foreach \x/\y in {0/0, 0/1, 1/0, -1/0, 0/-1, 1/-1, -1/1}
\filldraw[black] (\x, \y) circle(1.5pt);

\draw[<->] (-2.0, 0) -- (2.0, 0) node[right]{\footnotesize $X_{1}$};
\draw[<->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) node[above]{\footnotesize $X_{2}$};

\foreach \x/\y/\direction in {0/1/above right, 1/0/above right, -1/0/above left, 0/-1/below left, 1/-1/below right, -1/1/above left}
\node [\direction] at (\x,\y) {\tiny $\left(\x, \y\right)$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note here that the length of the semi-minor axis is approximately the square root of `0.58^2 + 0.58^2`.

### Edit

I have used `\foreach` in the above codes to make them shorter.